# Azure Search datasource with integrated change tracking

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to create an Azure Search datasource using SQL Integrated change tracking. My DB is SQL Azure V12. I've enabled change tracking for the target table (News) - I've checked and double checked. But still when I'm trying to create a DataSource, I get the error:

> Integrated change tracking is not enabled for table 'dbo.News'.

Here are my settings:

```
{
    "name": "news-titles",
    "type": "azuresql",
    "credentials": { "connectionString": "..." },
    "container": { "name": "dbo.News" },
    "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": { "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.SqlIntegratedChangeTrackingPolicy" }
}
```

Comment: Can you check actually change tracking is enabled for the database and tables? SELECT * FROM sys.change_tracking_databases  WHERE database_id=DB_ID(DBName) and select * from sys.change_tracking_tables where object_id
 = object_id ('News')

Comment: @SirishaChamarthi , I've tried this - it shows my table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your data source definition, try to specify the table name without the "dbo." prefix, as just "News".
HTH,
Eugene

Comment: thanks much! It helped. This is so not obvious, that I think it should be added to MSDN help pages:)

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I have passed this information on and we will make this more obvious in the documentation. Sorry for the confusion.